# bibliography problem

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

This is what I write with latex:

```
\documentclass{iserc}

 \begin{document}
 ...
\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\bibliography{my-biblio}
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

but when I compile it, it gives me an error:

```
!Latex error: something's wrong-- perhaps a missing \item
```

Answer (score 12):

Are you using BibTeX? If so you need to remove the `\begin{bibliography}` and `\end{bibliography}`. i.e.

```
\documentclass{iserc}

\begin{document}
 ...
\bibliographystyle{unsrt} % <- Choose a style. Your document class may do this for you.
\bibliography{my-biblio}

\end{document}
```

You will need to run `pdflatex` (or whatever LaTeX variant you use), then `bibtex` and then `pdflatex` twice more to get everything settled.

If you are using direct input from a file (this is very unlikely), then use `\input{my-biblio}` rather than `\bibliography{...}` and keep the `\begin{bibliography}` and `\end{bibliography}`.

Journals commonly ask for your bibliography to be placed directly in the LaTeX document. Perhaps this is where the confusion arose. When you need to do this, use the code above, and when you send it to the journal, copy the contents of the `.bbl` file and replace the `\bibliographystyle{...}` and `\bibliography{...}` lines with the content.

Comment: Yes I'm using bibTex, I have tried  what you said too, and it works, but I want the references to be in the order of their appearance, so I tried \bibliographystyle{urst} or {IEEEtr} but none of them changed the order of references!

Comment: `unsrt` (note the spelling, it's wrong in your comment but I'm guessing not in your document) should do what you want, so I'm not sure what's going on there.

Comment: It could be that the document class itself is causing the problem. What happens with `unsrt` and, say, `\documentckass{article}`?

Comment: Sorry for the typo, yes it's correct in my file. How should I run `bibtex`?

Comment: It doesn't compile with `\documentckass{article}` and `unsrt`

Comment: What editor are you using? If there is a `LaTeXmk` option this may be the easiest, and it'll do everything for you. If you don't have that, then your editor should have a `BibTeX` mode, probably in a drop down menu.

Comment: I'm using WinEdt

Comment: I'm looking at the style file you're using. It declares the `plainnat` bibliography style. If you are sending the document to ISERC 2012, then do not try to change it. They obviously want it this way. If you *really* want it to change, at the bottom of `iserc.cls` (the class file they gave you) change `\bibliographystyle{plainnat}` to `\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}`.

Comment: Thank you very much Mark, although they are using `plainnat ` in their template the references are in order of appearance and the reviewer wants me to change the order. but even after I changed the  `iserc.cls` it doesn't make in in order!

Comment: In WinEdt BibTeX is in the TeX menu. Remember to rerun LaTeX, BibTeX, LaTeX, LaTeX to reset the order!

Comment: It still doesn't chage the order!

Comment: All I can do is suggest you delete the `.aux` file and the `latex`, `bibtex`, `latex`, `latex` sequence again. Make sure that you have save the changes in the `iserc.cls` file and that it's in the same directory as your `.tex` file before you do.